# Source Urls having '#' in them (anchor links) are not redirecting

Tags: tomcat7, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I currently have a redirect filter working on an old site with 100+ html pages (static site). However, the remaining API docs (200+ pages) which all have a "#" in them are not redirecting. The original site was implemented as an SPA and hence had anchor links for all API docs; the target site have clean urls.

Snippet of UrlRedirectFilter

```
<rule>
<name>Delete Transactions</name>
<from>^/api/#create-transaction-deletion$</from>
<to last="true" type="redirect">https://baseurl/apis/Transaction/deleteTransactions</to>
```

```
<rule>
<name>Payment Charge</name>
<from>^/api/#paymentcharge$</from>
<to last="true" type="redirect">https://baseurl/apis/Payment%20Method/PaymentMethodCharge/</to>
```

Is there a hidden rule in url tuckey filter that discards anchor links? Is there a regex I need to be aware of? If none of the regex patterns work on the filter, what's the best way to move forward by extending urlrewriteFilter? Thanks!

Comment: Anchors are never sent to the server, they are client side only.

Comment: But anchors form a legitimate part of a URL (clientside SPAs).